ffmpeg claims "No capable devices found" for hevc nvenc encoding despite having supported gpu
I'm trying to transcode an mp4 video to hevc nvenc using the following command:
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -c:v hevc_nvenc output.mkv
But I keep getting the error shown at the end of this post. I'm using an RTX 3060 laptop GPU, which is shown to support HEVC encoding and decoding in this website : https://developer.nvidia.com/video-encode-and-decode-gpu-support-matrix-new.
I've tried transcoding to h.264 nvenc, and with h.265 without nvenc, using the command lines:
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -c:v h264_nvenc -c:a copy output.mkv
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx265 -c:a copy output.mkv
and they both worked, so it seems the problem is only hevc nvenc.
Here is the output for hevc nvenc, any help would be greatly appreciated:
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libquirc --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libxevd --enable-libzvbi --enable-libqrencode --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libvvenc --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxeve --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      59. 31.100 / 59. 31.100
  libavcodec     61. 11.100 / 61. 11.100
  libavformat    61.  5.101 / 61.  5.101
  libavdevice    61.  2.100 / 61.  2.100
  libavfilter    10.  2.102 / 10.  2.102
  libswscale      8.  2.100 /  8.  2.100
  libswresample   5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libpostproc    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.16.100
  Duration: 00:02:06.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4153 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4014 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> hevc (hevc_nvenc))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[hevc_nvenc @ 00000147092cb0c0] Codec not supported
[hevc_nvenc @ 00000147092cb0c0] No capable devices found
[vost#0:0/hevc_nvenc @ 000001470929e980] Error while opening encoder - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height.
[vf#0:0 @ 00000147092cb440] Error sending frames to consumers: Generic error in an external library
[vf#0:0 @ 00000147092cb440] Task finished with error code: -542398533 (Generic error in an external library)
[vf#0:0 @ 00000147092cb440] Terminating thread with return code -542398533 (Generic error in an external library)
[vost#0:0/hevc_nvenc @ 000001470929e980] Could not open encoder before EOF
[vost#0:0/hevc_nvenc @ 000001470929e980] Task finished with error code: -22 (Invalid argument)
[vost#0:0/hevc_nvenc @ 000001470929e980] Terminating thread with return code -22 (Invalid argument)
[out#0/matroska @ 00000147090f37c0] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no packets.
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0KiB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A
Conversion failed!


Try with FFmpeg version 7.0.2 from gyan.dev. Download
ffmpeg-release-full.7z. Try updating NVIDIA GPU driver.

Thanks for the reply. I've tried the latest ffmpeg version and nvidia driver. I also tried older nvidia drivers, because I used to be able to encode hevc nvenc a while back. Unfortunately nothing worked

For eliminating the chance that the input video file is related, try: ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=384x216:rate=1:duration=30 -c:v hevc_nvenc -bf 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4. Execute nvidia-smi, for making sure that the NVIDIA GPU is enabled (I am not sure that nvidia-smi is the right tool, but there is a chance that the laptop turns off the NVIDIA GPU for saving power). You may also try older version of FFmpeg like FFmpeg 5.1.4.

I've tried the command line you've provided, but I still receive the same error "[hevc_nvenc @ 0000023b17308fc0] Codec not supported
[hevc_nvenc @ 0000023b17308fc0] No capable devices found". I've tried the older version of ffmpeg that you linked, but unfortunately that didn't work. I've run nvidia-smi, and the output showed only the RTX 3060 gpu, which makes sense since I've enabled a setting in my laptop which disables the integrated gpu. I've also tried nvidia-smi -q to get a more detailed log, but I'm not exactly sure what to look for.

I've also done a clean install of windows before your last suggestion just to make sure that the issue is not due a corrupt file or something similar.

I found NVEncC utility. Executing NVEncC64.exe --check-features shows relevant supported features of NVENC.

Can you try this command:
ffmpeg -v 0 -encoders | findstr "nvenc"

On my rig, I get this output:
V....D av1_nvenc            NVIDIA NVENC av1 encoder (codec av1)
V....D h264_nvenc           NVIDIA NVENC H.264 encoder (codec h264)
V....D hevc_nvenc           NVIDIA NVENC hevc encoder (codec hevc)

This would at least confirm that your ffmpeg has these encoders present.
